# How to remove trailing spaces from text

Tags: string, google-sheets, trim

In a Google spreadsheet I have some data imported from a .csv file  which is loc A1 = 123.4 followed by 2 spaces

I want to use the numeric value but the spreadsheet refuses to recognize the string as a number.

The obvious answer is  substitute(A1;" ";"")  but this does not work!!. Nor do any of the other string search commands.

Am I going insane?

I am using a Mac running 10.4.7 and chrome

Comment: Any chance you can share the spreadsheet? Or, create a sanitized copy of it to share? You should be able to use the `Trim` function to remove leading/trailing whitespace.  I am not able to replicate what you describe, when I try it, it works as expected.

Comment: Here is a sample ss: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At10iMTcjaLDdE9yUFhUUEh3Y3NRdHE0UzFyb2lQLWc&usp=sharing

Comment: @DavidZemens The problem seem to come from the fact that when imported, number strings with trailing spaces are treated as strings whereas if they are typed they are treated as numeric.

Comment: This is peculiar. After the `Trim` or `Substitute` functions, I check the `Len` and it is still "6", which is obviously not correct. Ordinarily, I would expect `=Value(Trim(A1))` to coerce the text in to a true numeric, but something is not right with these data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you have already solved this... try this...this seems to be working

```
=Value(Substitute(A13,CHAR(160), ""))
```

or

```
=Substitute(A13,CHAR(160), "")*1
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the answer I provided 3 hours earlier. .

Answer (score 1):

OK. I've examined this in Excel (where I'm more handy with VBA/etc) and these are not ordinary "spaces" in your cell, they are actually non-breaking spaces, an ascii chr value of 160 (ordinary space is `Chr(32)`).

Try this formula to replace the non-breaking space character with a null string:

`=SUBSTITUTE(A13,CHAR(160),"")`

Excel has a function called `Clean()` which removes non-printing characters like this, but I do not see this function in Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @kaushai and @davidzemens

I have edited line 22 of the sheet.

It shows that  =Substitute(A4,CHAR(160), "")  is not numeric

however =Substitute(A4,CHAR(160), "")*1 is numeric

and      =value(Substitute(A4,CHAR(160), "")) is numeric